# How to access a ModelForm's fields in Django view

Tags: python, django, forms

I would like to enter the fields' values after my `ModelForm` instance is posted. I have three forms and every step one form is posted. I would like to make a logging system to save data to database until the user saves finishes all three forms. One of the forms is a `ModelForm`.

In my `forms.py` file:

```
class StepOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['name', 'difficulty', 'content']
```

I would like to access the form's field values after it has been posted in my view class, like this:

```
class MyView(views.View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = StepOne(request.POST)
        content = form.content
        difficulty = form.difficulty
        ....
```

Is there such thing possible?

Comment: Really you should use a FormView and do this logic in the `form_valid` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` in order to access the form data:

```
form = StepOne(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    content = form.cleaned_data['content']
    difficulty = form.cleaned_data['difficulty']
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).